# Using the terminal to update Twitter

Tags: command-line, twitter

Trying to update twitter using the terminal. curl and wget codes I have found are not working, it looks like Twitter has updated the way it authenticates, is it still possible to update Twitter from command line?

This code is just saying Basic authentication is not supported.
`curl -u user -d status="Tweeting from the shell" http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml`

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely worth to take a look at [Rainbow Stream](http://www.rainbowstream.org/) - a fancy Twitter client on Terminal wrote by Python :)

Comment: Hi, welcome to AU. about the answer I should say for the cases which You do not refer to the exact answer It should be add your help on the comments. By the way thanks for sharing your information on the stack

Comment: I got it, sorry for the 1st time :(

Comment: just stack policy. have fun :)