# Twitter command line client

Tags: command-line, software-recommendation, twitter

I would like to find a command line Twitter client  that has at least the following features :

- Retrieve my feed list
- Post Tweet
- List my notifications

Is there an application, preferably without manually using curl and the Twitter API ?

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries ?

Comment: Yes thanks, but I would like to see if there are fully functional, installable application that exist. If not I will use one of Python library.

Comment: You could look at http://www.rainbowstream.org/.

Comment: Related or duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/q/44847/367990

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This list is not exhaustive, there are other options out there.

### [oysttyer](https://github.com/oysttyer/oysttyer)

This is the surviving offspring of [TTYtter](http://www.floodgap.com/software/ttytter/) the first command line Twitter client to emerge (based on Perl). This is likely still the most popular of these programmes. I couldn not find an installer, but it should work simply by checking it out from GitHub and running the script.

[image]

### [t](https://github.com/sferik/t)

A Ruby based Twitter terminal client. You need to install Ruby and configure a few things, but it is not too complicated. Interaction is made using the `t` command followed by a specific option. Short review and install instructions are available at [Xmodulo](http://xmodulo.com/access-twitter-command-line-linux.html).

[image]

### [Rainbow Stream](http://www.rainbowstream.org/)

A Python based Twitter client with loadsa features, including image display on the console. The user interacts through a twitter specific command line. It is relatively easy to install, you can find instructions [at GitHub](https://github.com/DTVD/rainbowstream).

[image]

## [Tweetx](https://code.google.com/p/tweetx/)

This Twitter client is written in C and uses the `ncurses` library, internally working as a mail client. This one you must compile it yourself, but it should be fairly easy.

[image]